# Thinking sphinx ts-delayed-delta Riddle error

Tags: thinking-sphinx, delay, delta-index

I have a curious error when a try to run rake task with RAILS_ENV=preproduction/production environments... uninitialized constant ThinkingSphinx::Configuration::Riddle

On development everything works fine... if a remove ts-delayed-delta gem everything works fine too.

Any ideas?

gems version:
rails 2.3.14
thinking_sphinx 1.4.14
delayed_job 2.0.7
ts-delayed-delta 1.1.3 (from git repo)